# firefox issue webpack dev server hot reloading Firefox can't establish a connection to the server /websocket

Tags: firefox, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a fairly simple react, redux application which uses webpack dev server with hot reloading.

It works fine in Chrome, Safari, Opera, however does not work at all in Firefox. giving the following error message:

***Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at the ws://localhost:5050/sockjs-node/044/0lchvqev/websockert***

This is very strange and hard to debug as it keeps trying to reload the page, and just gives the error message

Comment: I'm seeing this error too, but it doesn't happen every time. I hit reload on the browser until it works. Seems like there's some sort of race condition that triggers about half the time (for me).